# OpenCl: How do I make use of INT4/8?

Tags: opencl

I am looking for ways to improve the efficiency of an algorithm based on OpenCl.

Currently I use `float` and `int` datatypes on a Radeon VII card. However, a datatype covering numbers between -8 to +7 would be sufficient.

According to following article the Radeon VII achieves peak performance of 53/110 TFlops when restricting to INT8/INT4, which is much higher than with `float` which is 14 TFlops.

https://www.pcgameshardware.de/Radeon-VII-Grafikkarte-268194/Tests/Benchmark-Review-1274185/2/

So my question is how can I make use of INT8/4 operations? Simply use datatype `char` instead of `int` in OpenCl? Since `char` is the smallest buildin datatype, how can I even use INT4?

Answer (score 4):

For "int8", that is, 8-bit integers, the OpenCL type is indeed `char` (signed, -128 to +127) or `uchar` (unsigned, 0 to 255). ***Not to be confused with the OpenCL type `int8`, which is a vector of 8 32-bit integers.***

For decent performance you may want to use vector versions of these such as `char4` or `char16`, though this should be driven based on your performance measurements, not guessing.

Note that you'll need to be aware of overflow behaviour, and especially for multiplications, you may need to perform intermediate operations on 16-bit values. (`short`/`ushort`/`short4`/`ushort16`/etc.) OpenCL also provides "saturating" addition and subtraction and [a few other helpful integer built-in functions](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/integerFunctions.html).

I'm not aware of any "native" support for packed 4-bit integer maths in OpenCL or any of the other GPGPU frameworks, or even any extensions. Maybe someone with experience with this can chip in, but my guess is that you'll effectively need to unpack `uchar` values using bit shifts and masking, perform your operations on `uchar` values and then pack back into 4-bit nibbles for storing. The speed boost will likely come from the fact that you can safely multiply using 8-bit logic rather than needing 16 bits to catch the overflow.

Comment: Using vector 'char4' seems like a good idea. The unpacking approach came also to my mind, but maybe will have some overhead: If my understanding is correct, the masking and bit shifting operations consume also cycles of the processing element. And maybe the addition with 'char' is in the end carried out in hardware with the same 32bit adder like for the 'int' type. Are you aware where I can find information about the underlying hardware of processing elements carrying out the arithmetics?

Comment: @piveloper The hardware vendor's OpenCL optimisation guide or similar is what you're looking for. As you mention Radeon VII, you'll probably want the AMD one. Specifically, Vega added a bunch of packed maths operations, which are mentioned [in section 6.7. of the Vega ISA document](https://developer.amd.com/wp-content/resources/Vega_Shader_ISA_28July2017.pdf). Looks like these are primarily 16-bit packed operations, nothing specific to 8 bit integers.

Comment: @piveloper The older [GCN optimisation guide](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2013/12/AMD_OpenCL_Programming_Optimization_Guide2.pdf) states "Packed 16-bit and 8-bit operations are not natively supported; however, in cases
where it is known that no overflow will occur, some algorithms may be able to
effectively pack 2 to 4 values into the 32-bit registers natively supported by the
hardware." So in my opinion, the almost 4x speedup quoted for 8-bit ints sounds a little suspicious, especially considering floating-point MAD is apparently 4x faster than 32-bit integer MAD.

Comment: Some Nvidia GPUs support the dp4a dot product accumulate instruction for 4 char packed into a 32-bit integer. This instruction performs 8 8-bit integer operations in the time of a single 32-bit integer operation. I guess AMD GPUs have a similar instruction. https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/#integer-arithmetic-instructions-dp4a

Answer (score 1):

I made a test with some kernels to see if there is any difference in performance between `int8` and `char8`:

```c
    typedef int8 type_msg;
    //typedef char8 type_msg;
    #define convert_type_msg(x) convert_int8(x)

    __kernel void some_operation(__global  type_msg *in_buff,
                                 __global  type_msg *out_buff)
    {
        out_buff[get_global_id(0)] = in_buff[get_global_id(0)] +(type_msg)(2);
    }
```

First, to see what happens on GPU I used CodeXL to get the assembler code.

Here is part of the assembler code where `int8` is used:

```c
    global_load_dwordx4  v[4:7], v[2:3], off
    global_load_dwordx4  v[8:11], v[2:3], off inst_offset:16
    v_add_co_u32  v0, vcc, s6, v0
    v_mov_b32     v2, s7
    v_addc_co_u32  v1, vcc, v2, v1, vcc
    s_waitcnt     vmcnt(0)
    v_add_u32     v8, 2, v8
    v_add_u32     v9, 2, v9
    v_add_u32     v10, 2, v10
    v_add_u32     v11, 2, v11
    global_store_dwordx4  v[0:1], v[8:11], off inst_offset
    v_add_u32     v2, 2, v4
    v_add_u32     v3, 2, v5
    v_add_u32     v4, 2, v6
    v_add_u32     v5, 2, v7
    global_store_dwordx4  v[0:1], v[2:5], off
```

And here is part of the assembler code where `char8` is used:

```c
    global_load_dwordx2  v[2:3], v[2:3], off
    s_waitcnt     vmcnt(0)
    v_lshlrev_b32  v4, 8, v3 src1_sel:BYTE_3
    v_lshrrev_b32  v5, 8, v3
    v_add_u32     v6, 2, v3 src1_sel:WORD_1
    v_add_u32     v4, 0x00000200, v4
    s_movk_i32    s0, 0x00ff
    v_lshlrev_b32  v7, 8, v2 src1_sel:BYTE_3
    v_add_u32     v5, 2, v5
    v_bfi_b32     v4, s0, v6, v4
    s_mov_b32     s1, 0x02010004
    v_lshrrev_b32  v6, 8, v2
    v_add_u32     v8, 2, v2 src1_sel:WORD_1
    v_add_u32     v7, 0x00000200, v7
    v_add_u32     v3, 2, v3
    v_perm_b32    v4, v5, v4, s1
    v_add_u32     v5, 2, v6
    v_bfi_b32     v6, s0, v8, v7
    v_add_co_u32  v0, vcc, s6, v0
    v_mov_b32     v7, s7
    v_addc_co_u32  v1, vcc, v7, v1, vcc
    v_perm_b32    v3, v3, v4, s1
    v_add_u32     v2, 2, v2
    v_perm_b32    v4, v5, v6, s1
    v_perm_b32    v2, v2, v4, s1
    global_store_dword  v[0:1], v3, off inst_offset:4
    global_store_dword  v[0:1], v2, off
```

I am no expert in assembly language, but as far as I can tell, in both cases there are 8 additions carried out using the `v_add_u32` operation. Also `char8` seems to require more operations like `v_perm_b32` and `v_bfi_b32`. Maybe someone can explain what these are doing.

The only benefit of using `char8` seems to be, that less global memory access is needed. E.g. there is only one `global_load_dwordx2` access for `char8` but 2 `global_load_dwordx4` accesses for `int8`.

Thus in terms of performance maybe `char8` is a little bit slower for computational bounded algorithms but faster for memory bounded algorithms.

To verify the analysis I build up a little experiment, where arithmetic is the bottleneck. To make sure that the compiler does not simplify the for-loop too much, I added some branching inside of it.

```c
    typedef int8 type_msg;
    #define convert_type_msg(x) convert_int8(x)

    //typedef char8 type_msg;
    //#define convert_type_msg(x) convert_char8(x)

    __kernel void some_complex_operation(__global  char8 *in_buff,
                                         __global  char8 *out_buff)
    {
        type_msg res = in_buff[get_global_id(0)];
        for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
        {
            res += select((type_msg)(-1), (type_msg)(4), res<(type_msg)100);
        }
        out_buff[get_global_id(0)] =(type_msg) res;
    }
```

On my system the average time (running 100 times) for

- `int8` is 0.0558 sec
- `char8` is 0.0754 sec
- `short8` is 0.0738 sec
- `long8` is 0.1105 sec

So `char8` consumes roughly 35 % more time. This confirms the observation, that in assembly language more instructions are generated for `char8`. However, some professional explanation for the addtional assembly statements would be nice.